# Hard bug sql + python (expected %d not str)

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I can't use executemany function at all from pymysql, I'm using this reduced example:

```
cursor = self.connection.cursor()
sql_query = f"UPDATE lançamento SET {column_name} = %s WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Data, '%d/%m/%Y') > %s AND Caixa = %s;"
cursor.executemany(sql_query, [(str(value), str(current_date), self.back_end_insert_caixa_name) for value in values])
```

all values are as str, but I get the exception:

```
%d format: a real number is required, not str
```

the type of column_name in my sql database is float but when I try change %s to %f and str(value) to float(value) I get this exception:

```
a real number is required not str
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: This is not a hard bug.  To use a literal % sign, you need to double it.  `STR_TO_DATE(Data, '%%d/%%m/%%Y')`.

Comment: However, since `current_date` and `self.back_end_insert_caixa_name` do not change, this is going to update the SAME record over and over and over.  Only the last value will survive.  This can't be what you really intended.

Comment: in SQL you don't care about the type, alwways use `%s` and `[(value, current_date, self.back_end_insert_caixa_name) for value in values]`  the SQL lib will handle everyting for you

Comment: so was the problem about using f string?